# webservice in jQuery returns collection type

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have an ASP.NET WebService that returns an object of List

```
public class Students
{
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

I am accessing this webservice using this jQuery code

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Students.asmx/GetStudents",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        $("#myDiv").html(msg.d);
    }
});
```

But all I get is Object object.

How can I get the data in that object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is [Object object] in jquery (when you inspect a jQuery object).

You are actually getting an array of Student objects; you can iterate through the results like this

```
for (x = 0; x < msg.length; x++) {
    alert(msg[x].StudentName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much..I forgot to mention that I am using jmsajax and not the $.ajax ..so when I do what you suggest..i get d.length is null or not an object.